# Get a URL argument variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, get, arguments

How do I get a $_GET[] argument with JavaScript?

http://www.example.com/?what=this

I want to get the value of "what" ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use the get paramater of the url in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827368/use-the-get-paramater-of-the-url-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [grab query string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349058/grab-query-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the raw string like this:

```
window.location.search
```

E.g., `http://google.com/?whatIs=up`

gives you `?whatIs=up`

And then parse through it to get the different values for the different parameters.