# How to read value from URI using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get query string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)
>   [grab query string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349058/grab-query-string-using-javascript)

I have one Form  URI, I need to read a specific ATTRIBUTE value. and set that value to one of the Same Form-filed.

Example:-`"formFieldName=UXCopy%3Abody&FCKAssetId=Variables.ContentDetails%3Aid&fielddesc=Body&FCKName=homecopy&AssetType=UXPage&StartItem=1299862617913&FCKAssetType=UXCopy&cs_environment=addref&pagename=OpenMarket%2FXcelerate%2FActions%2FNewContentFront&embedtype=link&adidiii=ssssssss&childtypes=UXDocument%2CUXEmbed%2CUXGoogleMap%2CUXImage%2CUXSocialMediaLink%2CUXPage&IFCKEditor=true&title=New&cancelpage=OpenMarket%2FXcelerate%2FActions%2FAddRefFront&assetid=Variables.assetid"`

I want to read `adidiii` Value and set this value to one of the Same Form Filed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newURI = oldURI.replace(/&adidiii\=.+[&$]/, "&adidiii=" + encodeURIComponent(**WhateverThisSameFormFieldIs**) + "&")
```

If you just want to get a parameter from the uri do this:

```
function getURIParam(URI, param)
{
    var match = URI.match(new RegExp("[\?&]" + param + "=([^&]+)"));
    return match[1] ? decodeURIComponent(match[1]) : null;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me how to get individual ATTRIBUTE values from URI, Do we have any js methods to get the value by passing ATTRIBUTE name. "document.URL."

Comment: Don't think so buddy, you're gonna have to stick with regular expressions really

Comment: i just tried with above code am getting this error "Cannot call method 'match' of undefined". do i need to explicitly define "match" method. am newbie in JavaScript, thanks in advance

Comment: You need to pass the uri to the function.

Comment: Finally i have return some js function,its working as per my requirement. thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to process the URL and return the values you are expecting out of it.

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

If you want to get the value of `adidiii` use the following code.

```
var field = getUrlVars()["adidiii"];

alert(field);
```

Hope this will help you.